# Strange behaviour of numpy vstack/c_ while stacking list of identical arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to stack three separate lists of mixed type into a matrix.

For example something like this works perfectly:

```
import numpy as np


In [31]:

c1 = [0, [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
c2 = [[1], 0, 0, [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], 0, [1]]
c3 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

In [32]:

np.c_[c1,c2,c3]

Out[32]:

array([[0, list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0]], dtype=object)

In [33]:

np.vstack((c1, c2, c3)).T

Out[33]:

array([[0, list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0]], dtype=object)
```

This respects the datatypes stored in the array. However as soon as any list consisting of identical arrays is added into mix, this happens:

```
In [28]:

c1 = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
c2 = [[1], 0, 0, [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], 0, [1]]
c3 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

In [29]:

np.c_[c1,c2,c3]

Out[29]:

array([[1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, 0, 1.0],
       [1, 0, 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0],
       [1, 0, 1.0],
       [1, list([1]), 1.0]], dtype=object)

In [30]:

np.vstack((c1, c2, c3)).T

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b54eaf7a5522> in <module>
----> 1 np.vstack((c1, c2, c3)).T

<__array_function__ internals> in vstack(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
    280     if not isinstance(arrs, list):
    281         arrs = [arrs]
--> 282     return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    283 
    284 

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 10
```

The only difference between the two codeblocks is that now list `c1` consists completely of elements `[1]` - using np.c_ converts this list to a flat list, I believe this is what breaks the np.vstack() too. 
Is there any way to get around this behavior ?

Edit: What I mean is, is there anyway to get something equivalent to this:

```
array([[list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0],
       [list([1]), 0, 1.0],
       [list([1]), list([1]), 1.0]], dtype=object)
```

when the first column is made completely of list of identical elements, be it strings, lists or anything else.

Comment: c1 gets cast to an array internally, which has a shape (10,1) You should do the conversion to arrays yourself prior to using np.c_ or np.vstack to ensure they are compatible

Comment: @NaN - this is a bit counter-intuitive. Since [[1],[1]] != [1,1], also it seems that numpy doesn't mind if it is [1,[1]] - it will be still treated as [1,[1]] while using np.vstack - which is confusing.

Comment: Look at `np.array(c1)`, c2,c3 individually.  Focus on shape.

Answer (score 2):

Both `c_` and `vstack` make arrays from the inputs.

```
In [8]: c1 = [0, [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]] 
   ...: c2 = [[1], 0, 0, [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], 0, [1]] 
   ...: c3 = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]                                
In [9]: np.array(c1)                                                                           
Out[9]: 
array([0, list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]),
       list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1])], dtype=object)
In [10]: np.array(c2)                                                                          
Out[10]: 
array([list([1]), 0, 0, list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]),
       list([1]), 0, list([1])], dtype=object)
In [11]: np.array(c3)                                                                          
Out[11]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

These are all (10,) 1d arrays.  Not so with the next `c1`.

```
In [12]: c1 = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]                               
In [13]: np.array(c1)                                                                          
Out[13]: 
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

`np.vstack` converts all the inputs to 2d arrays.  That is the 1d arrays now have shape (1,10).  These are `concatenate` on the fist axis to make a (3,10) array.

In the last case the (10,1) cannot be joined with the (1,10) arrays.

`np.c_` does some more complicated shape adjustment.  But in short what's doing here is turning all arrays into (10,1) shape, and concatenting on the 2nd axis.  `np.column_stack` does the same thing.

Or using the underlying `concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate([np.array(c1), np.array(c2)[:,None], np.array(c3)[:,None]],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is a rather peculiar scenario and this behavior can be replicated by using 'np.column_stack' too. Is there any way to avoid this casting/mutation of shapes?

Comment: I showed the basic operation  Turn all lists into arrays, adjust dimensions as needed, and use concatenate.

Comment: But it still doesn't solve the problem - turning every list into numpy arrays and adjusting the dimensions allows the concatenation to happen, but the type of elements in in list `c1` is still changing to `int` from `[]` - which is not the desired outcome.

Comment: `np.array` is not a reliable way of making an object dtype array